# Manual Fulltext index population time in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I would like to know if there is a way to see how much time did it take SQL Server 2012 to index all the data in a table?

In my example I create the table, create the index and set the population to be manual. Then I execute

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name START UPDATE POPULATION;
```

The query executes immediately but as I know, the population process is actually performed in the background. How can I find out what's the total time it took to index the whole table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sys.fulltext_indexes` system table contains the start/end time of the current or last population (crawl).

```
SELECT crawl_start_date, crawl_end_date
FROM sys.fulltext_indexes
```

Comment: Thanks, that query is convinient too. I was also suggested to look at the log files created after every population as described here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx#crawl.